# Couldn't add two containers within a container

Tags: magento2.4.3

I'm trying This code

```
<container name="the.app.body" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="theApp-body">

            <container name="slider.section" htmlTag="section" htmlClass="pt-xxl bg-primary text-white">

                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="home_slider" template="Magento_Cms::slider/slider.phtml"/>

            </container>

            <container name="products.slider" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="bg-gray pb-xxl">

                <container name="product.container.slider" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="container">

                    <container name="product.slider" htmlTag="section" htmlClass="pt-xxl">

                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="home_slider" template="Magento_Cms::products/pslider.phtml"/>

                    </container>

                </container>


            </container>

        </container>
```

and the `products.slider` Container overrides the `slider.section` container and I don't know how or why !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your template blocks have the same `name` attribute value of `home_slider`. Change them to be unique and your XML construction should render correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much !!, I almost went crazy !